# How do I tally how many times a word appears on a certain row?

Tags: vba, excel

I have four sets of data representing a softball schedule. Looks like this:

```
    Day     Team 1     Team 2
    M       A Team     B Team
    T       C Team     D Team
```

....

but four times over. I want to be able to change the schedule and have it automatically tally how many times a team plays on a given day. Ideas?

Comment: Are you look for a message box that says like Monday Team A plays 5 times...etc or a bunch of cells that count how many times a team plays on that day?

Comment: Please show more data and your expected output.

Comment: I suppose the expected output would be a table with 5 columns, headed Mon, Tues, Wed, Thu, Fri and 10 rows, Team A, Team B, etc. When the routine is over, the table should tell me how many teams each team played each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would us something like this:

```
=COUNTIF(2:2,"A Team")
```

Edit:

You can use a SUMPRODUCT() Function with math operands `*` and `+`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$43=H$1)*(($B$2:$B$43=$G2)+($C$2:$C$43=$G2)))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

So how it works:

Since TRUE/FALSE is a Boolean and it can be reduced to 1/0 respectively.  Using the `*` and `+` operands is like `AND` and `OR` respectively.

The SUMPRODUCT iterates through the range and test each criterion inside the `()`  So it first test whether the cell in column A is equal to H1, if so it returns a 1, or a 0 if not.  the next part sets up the `OR` if in the same row the team name is found it also returns a 1.  1 * 1 = 1.  SUMPRODUCT keeps track of all the 1 and 0 and adds them together, so you get the count.

If there are other columns that have the team names just add those columns with the `+` area.

Comment: yea but then you get something like this:

=SUM(COUNTIF(E34:F34,C42),COUNTIF(K34:L34,C42),COUNTIF(E29:F29,C42),COUNTIF(K29:L29,C42),COUNTIF(K24:L24,C42),COUNTIF(K19:L19,C42),COUNTIF(E19:F19,C42),COUNTIF(E14:F14,C42),COUNTIF(E9:F9,C42),COUNTIF(K9:L9,C42),COUNTIF(K4:L4,C42),COUNTIF(E4:F4,C42))

which is very very messy, and that's just for 1 of the 10 teams!!

Comment: I think I need to see more of your data, repost your photo link.

Comment: @Brad - Please post more data. Probably can combine the `Countif()` with a `vlookup()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's start with making your table a real table via "Start > format as table" and call your table "data". Then you have three columns called data[Day], data[Team 1] and data[Team 2]. For instance this:

```
Day         Team 1   Team 2
Monday      A Team   B team
Tuesday     C Team   D Team
Wednesday   C Team   A Team
Monday      B Team   C Team
```

Now comes the ugly part. You need a matrix of 7*10 (days * teams)

```
(Cell E1)    Team 1    Team 2    Team 3    Team 4    ...
Monday      *1
Tuesday     
Wednesday
...
```

Formula *1

```
=SUMPRODUCT((data[Day]=$E2)*((data[Team 1]=F$1)+(data[Team 2]=F$1)))
```

Now drag down that formula till Sunday and then copy it to the other teams (when I tried dragging it to the other teams, Excel messed up the column names!).

This will automatically fill the matrix and tell you which team plays how often on a specific day.

What does it do? Basically SUMPRODUCT can not only build products, but it can also evaluate boolean conditions. So if on Monday, Team A plays, then the first column would return (for Team A / Monday):

```
1*(1+0)
```

SUMPRODUCT does that for each line in the matrix and then sums up the result.